# Loading FXML from a pastebin

Tags: javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

I'm working on an JavaFX program which needs to load the fxml source from this URL: `http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=SW5d5ucs`

```xml
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="201.0" prefWidth="299.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2B2B2B;" fx:controller="aio_pkhonor.core.ui.crafting.CraftingInterfaceController" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
<children>
<Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="6.0" layoutY="6.0" prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="291.0" text="Gem Crafting" textFill="WHITE">
<font>
<Font name="Rod" size="28.0"/>
</font>
</Label>
<Button fx:id="StartButton" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="162.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="273.0" style="-fx-background-color: #1b1b1b;" text="Start Script" textFill="WHITE"/>
<Label layoutX="28.0" layoutY="120.0" text="Gem To Craft : " textFill="WHITE"/>
<ComboBox fx:id="GemComboBox" layoutX="108.0" layoutY="116.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="163.0" promptText="Select Gem"/>
<RadioButton fx:id="AutoTrainButton" layoutX="24.5439453125" layoutY="57.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="AutoTrain (Trains Your Acc To 2Bil XP)" textFill="WHITE">
<toggleGroup>
<ToggleGroup fx:id="group"/>
</toggleGroup>
</RadioButton>
<RadioButton fx:id="CustomTrainButton" layoutX="25.0" layoutY="84.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Custom" textFill="WHITE" toggleGroup="$group"/>
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I have tried things but can't seem to figure it out, it would be great if someone could help me out.

Comment: Do you mean you want to load the FXML that's shown there, or do you literally mean you want to download the FXML from that location at runtime? Either way, can you show the code you tried and explain what went wrong when you tried it?

Comment: well i tried using DOM parser, i dont mind how its loaded as long if i can use the fxml to show my JavaFX application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the controller on your classpath, you can just do

```
import java.net.URL;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class RemoteFXMLTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(new URL("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=SW5d5ucs"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Or you could just copy the code, save it to an FXML file, and use it in the standard way...